# How to read calendars which are shared by others in Office 365 REST API

Tags: office365, office365api

https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/Users/me/calendars

I used this one to get all my calendars. I've got all calendars except calendars which are shared by others with me. I just want to read these calendars. My question is: Does Office 365 Rest Api support my scenario - read calendars shared by others with me? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. Right now the API only supports accessing **your** data, it doesn't support accessing other folks, even if they've given you access. This is a feature we are looking at adding, but I don't have a timeline to share.

Comment: I try to follow this one [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) . So, I build a service app which can access all data from office 365 and then my client app can retrieve data from service app, am i right?

Comment: Correct. The organizational admin has to grant your app access, but then it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Johnston . I have one more question: Does Office 365 REST API support sharing user's calendar with others?

Comment: No, it doesn't support modifying sharing permissions.