# oauth2 connect in microsoft

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

How can I get events from Office 365 Calendar, from REST?

I create an application in Azure, I have Token from this request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
  client_id=[app_id from AZURE]
  &response_type=code
  &redirect_uri=https://mypage_domain.com
  &response_mode=query
  &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.read%20
  &state=12345
```

Next i try get Events:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$postFields = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$authCode.'&redirect_uri='.$redirectUri.'&scope=openid&client_id='.$clientId.'&client_secret='.$clientSecret;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$serverOutput = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$jsonOutput = json_decode($serverOutput, true);

$chUser = curl_init();
$headersUser[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$jsonOutput['id_token'];
curl_setopt($chUser, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/');
curl_setopt($chUser, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($chUser, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersUser);
$serverOutputUser = curl_exec($chUser);
curl_close($chUser);
```

But I get an error: `Access token validation failure`.

What did I do wrong? 
I found examples for Laravel but I  need simple, universal code. I need use this in Wordpress to write events from calendar for page users.

Comment: `$jsonOutput['id_token']` try using the `access_token` instead :)

Comment: Id token is for your app, access token is for the API you want to call.

Comment: What language is this? My eyes hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indicating wrong authorization header. In fact, the authorization header uses bearer token which has the structure: `Bearer <access_token>`.

```
$headersUser[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$jsonOutput['**access_token**'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed to 'access_token' but it still does not work. I have the same error. Maybe because I'm getting the token from the domain "login.microsoftonline.com", and tries to use it on the domain "graph.microsoft.com" ?

Comment: No, getting from login.microsoftonline.com is correct. Graph.microsoft.com is just scope you need to have access before you can retrieve calendar information. Could you debug to see what was wrong? Could you post the entire request body?

Comment: I have this error: `{ "error": { "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "Access token validation failure.", "innerError": { "request-id": "8bda012b-dddc-4a4a-9ad8-36fbeb843d78", "date": "2018-02-28T13:39:39" } } }`. Maybe I have wrong scope? `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[cliend_id_from_app]&redirect_uri=[redirect_url]&response_type=code&scope=https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read`

Comment: Yes look at this for scope of outlook https://stackoverflow.com/q/40381513/9330826

Comment: I change scope to `https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read.shared` and works. Thank you for your help.